# Does the Transliteration module alter the existing URLs?

Tags: 7, transliteration

I want to install the Transliteration module for a site on Drupal.

If I install this module, would it also change existing URLs (if I enabled it in the Pathauto module settings), or would it change just the new urls? I don't to alter the existing URLs.

Answer (score 0):

The Transliteration module doesn't update anything on its own. It's the Pathauto that controls that. Just enabling the Transliteration won't do anything.

Pathauto module has a setting for what happens when an entity is updated (`/admin/config/search/path/settings`). This means that when you edit existing content Pathauto may change the alias depending on your settings.

You can set it to `Do nothing. Leave the old alias intact.` This way you'll be able to edit old content without the alias being automatically changed.

If you need to use some other `Update action` setting you'll have to remember each time when editing an "old" node to untick the option `Generate automatic URL alias` and use the "old" alias manually.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! New content will be processed however right?

Comment: @SumitK Yes, it will be.

Comment: Thanks as per advice here I installed the module and things are working as they should